# How can I check that my iOS app is reviewed & rated by a user or not from my code

Tags: iphone, rating

If someone reviews my application, is it possible to get an event? I am using a third party library for managing app ratings. It is the most popular iOS rating library called iRate. iRate has an method:

```
[[iRate sharedInstance] ratedThisVersion]
```

But it seems, it is not working when I tried to test. Is there any native way to check that my app is reviewed by user or not?

Comment: No, since you can not find out wether the user has reviewed your app in the AppStore. Since Apple does not provide any API to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library `iRate` stores the fact that a user rated an app in it's user defaults. As a result, you will only be able to tell if a user rated the version once you've actually set the value, using assignment.

Just as a matter of interest, ratedThisVersion is a BOOL property, not a message - so it's `[iRate sharedInstance].ratedThisVersion` and `[iRate sharedInstance].ratedThisVersion = YES;` for assignment.

There's no current mechanism in the apple store to determine if the user has rated the app. You can ask for the number of reviews for an app by using the itunes search api (e.g. getting the output from `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=364147881` would get the json data for the BBC news app, which as of my checking had an `"averageUserRating": 4` and `"userRatingCount": 30937`).